# Android post request escape character

Tags: java, android, http, escaping, character

How do you escape the character "ü" in a string.

I have this character in my json data:

```
{"Name": "Hyüsin"}
```

when I do a HttpPost in my android to the webServer. it gives me a "Bad Request" error as response.

HttpPost Code:

```
    // uploads the data
public class UploadData extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... url) {

            try {

                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(LogInActivity.SERVICE_URI + url[0]);

                request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");


                //THIS IS  {"Name": "Hyüsin"}               
                JSONObject jsonTaakkaart = taakkaart.serializeToObj();




                StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonTaakkaart .toString());
                request.setEntity(entity);


                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);


                return true;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonTaakkaart.toString(), "UTF-8");
```

to specify that the encoding is UTF-8.